# Почему при входе под встроенной учетной записью "Администратор" cmd и остальные процессы вызываются не от имени администратора?

Tags: windows

Активировал встроенную учетную запись администратора командой `net user Администратор /active:yes`. Сменил учетную запись, вызвал cmd - ожидалось что запустится она от имени администратора. Почему не так?
P.S. OS Windows 10

Comment: UAC: Пуск -> "Найти программы и файлы" -> UAC -> Параметры управления учетными записями пользователей. Настроить уровень выдачи уведомлений до необходимого.

Comment: UAC выставлено в "никогда не уведомлять" - проблема не в нем

Comment: `whoami` чё говорит?

Comment: редактор групповой политики: Конфиг.комп. -> Конф. Windows -> Лок. политики -> Параметры безоп.:  **Контроль учетных записей: использование режима одобрения администратором для встроенной учетной записи администратора** что задано? Может в значениях аналогичных параметров того же раздела, есть значения, препятствующие нужному поведению?

Comment: whoami вывел `desktop-61jpjso\администратор`;
параметры безопасности (http://www.screencast.com/t/ubqPpGdxmm), вроде все выставлено как надо